# Sharing Macbook's WiFi connection to other device via wired connection

Tags: wifi, internet-sharing

My MacBook Pro (2017 ver. / no ethernet port) is connected to a WiFi connection and I am trying to use Internet Sharing so that I can connect my Philips Hue Bridge to the internet. I quickly bought a USB-C to Ethernet adapter from Amazon thinking that would work but I am guessing this can only be used to get an internet connection to my MacBook from a router/modem, instead of sharing the connection from the MacBook to another device?

Any insights/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you can share an internet connection from one network interface over another interface using the [**Internet Sharing**](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-internet-connection-mac-network-users-mchlp1540/mac) feature in the **Sharing** system preference.

In your case, you would share **from** your Wi-Fi connection **to** your Ethernet adapter, similar to this:

[image: Internet Sharing section in Sharing preferences pane, showing Wi-Fi sharing to Ethernet adapter]

Comment: Could you please recommend an Ethernet adapter that would support an 'outgoing' internet connection from the MacBook to another device? (maybe one that supports USB-C). Thanks!!!

Comment: @JakeB. Any well-behaved Ethernet adapter should work; to the adapter, it simply looks like you're connecting your target device to just another router. Can you share the exact brand & model of your adapter in your question, if it's misbehaving?